How to get a responsive/animated CSS Hamburger menu on Wordpress using a themed Header
The theme I use is Astra for Wordpress. I implemented a hamburger menu for the website on mobile devices and I want it to be animated. I tried to overwrite the style with a custom CSS and Javascript but everytime I emptied the cache und relaoded the page there was no animation at all.
thats the HTML for the Menu when its in ita normal state:
<button type="button" class="menu-toggle main-header-menu-toggle ast-mobile-menu-trigger-fill" aria-expanded="false" data-index="0" style="display: flex;">
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Main Menu</span>
                    <span class="mobile-menu-toggle-icon">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="ahfb-svg-iconset ast-inline-flex svg-baseline"><svg class="ast-mobile-svg ast-menu2-svg" fill="currentColor" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="28" viewBox="0 0 24 28"><path d="M24 21v2c0 0.547-0.453 1-1 1h-22c-0.547 0-1-0.453-1-1v-2c0-0.547 0.453-1 1-1h22c0.547 0 1 0.453 1 1zM24 13v2c0 0.547-0.453 1-1 1h-22c-0.547 0-1-0.453-1-1v-2c0-0.547 0.453-1 1-1h22c0.547 0 1 0.453 1 1zM24 5v2c0 0.547-0.453 1-1 1h-22c-0.547 0-1-0.453-1-1v-2c0-0.547 0.453-1 1-1h22c0.547 0 1 0.453 1 1z"></path></svg></span><span aria-hidden="true" class="ahfb-svg-iconset ast-inline-flex svg-baseline"><svg class="ast-mobile-svg ast-close-svg" fill="currentColor" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5.293 6.707l5.293 5.293-5.293 5.293c-0.391 0.391-0.391 1.024 0 1.414s1.024 0.391 1.414 0l5.293-5.293 5.293 5.293c0.391 0.391 1.024 0.391 1.414 0s0.391-1.024 0-1.414l-5.293-5.293 5.293-5.293c0.391-0.391 0.391-1.024 0-1.414s-1.024-0.391-1.414 0l-5.293 5.293-5.293-5.293c-0.391-0.391-1.024-0.391-1.414 0s-0.391 1.024 0 1.414z"></path></svg></span>                  </span>
                                    </button>

an thats the HTML when the X is visible:
<button type="button" class="menu-toggle main-header-menu-toggle ast-mobile-menu-trigger-fill" aria-expanded="false" data-index="0" style="display: flex;">
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Main Menu</span>
                    <span class="mobile-menu-toggle-icon">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="ahfb-svg-iconset ast-inline-flex svg-baseline"><svg class="ast-mobile-svg ast-menu2-svg" fill="currentColor" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="28" viewBox="0 0 24 28"><path d="M24 21v2c0 0.547-0.453 1-1 1h-22c-0.547 0-1-0.453-1-1v-2c0-0.547 0.453-1 1-1h22c0.547 0 1 0.453 1 1zM24 13v2c0 0.547-0.453 1-1 1h-22c-0.547 0-1-0.453-1-1v-2c0-0.547 0.453-1 1-1h22c0.547 0 1 0.453 1 1zM24 5v2c0 0.547-0.453 1-1 1h-22c-0.547 0-1-0.453-1-1v-2c0-0.547 0.453-1 1-1h22c0.547 0 1 0.453 1 1z"></path></svg></span><span aria-hidden="true" class="ahfb-svg-iconset ast-inline-flex svg-baseline"><svg class="ast-mobile-svg ast-close-svg" fill="currentColor" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5.293 6.707l5.293 5.293-5.293 5.293c-0.391 0.391-0.391 1.024 0 1.414s1.024 0.391 1.414 0l5.293-5.293 5.293 5.293c0.391 0.391 1.024 0.391 1.414 0s0.391-1.024 0-1.414l-5.293-5.293 5.293-5.293c0.391-0.391 0.391-1.024 0-1.414s-1.024-0.391-1.414 0l-5.293 5.293-5.293-5.293c-0.391-0.391-1.024-0.391-1.414 0s-0.391 1.024 0 1.414z"></path></svg></span>                  </span>
                                    </button> 

Unfortunately i cant change the HTML because its preloaded by the Astra Theme.
Is there any chance I can overwrite it? I even tried to force the CSS but it didnt work either.
Thanks
Tried to overwrite with a new CSS or JS

Your 2 shown HTML are identical. All your menu items (categories..) are added dynamicaly from database in wordpress. You can still achieve  your menu styling as you wish using css and javascript. If you are using WP code make sure to use DOMContentLoaded event listener (to make sure that DOM element are loaded when selecting them). You can also enqeue your JS and styling. For css changing take into account specificity

Use your browser inspector to check if your custom CSS is being loaded. If not, then where are you adding your custom CSS? In the theme settings somewhere? Or in Appearance > Customise > Additional CSS?
